# Determine if docker image built locally or pulled from repo?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to tell if a Docker image was built locally or pulled from a remote repository?

Clarification:
We have large images (15+ GB) that are automated builds in Docker HUB. During development/testing it's often faster to build these images locally but using the same tags so that they can be used in building downstream images. It would be useful if we could to determine if a given image was built locally or downstream.

Comment: Images pulled from a remote repository should have a repository when you run `docker images`, no? You can apply a filter to view images with a repository

Comment: @OluwafemiSule `docker images` doesn't work as we'll build the image using the same tags (`org/image-name`) as are used in Docker Hub. I updated the question to provide more context.

Comment: The output of 'Docker history <image-id>' would show <missing> in the image name for every layer that was built outside the local docker host. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this minimal `Dockerfile`

```
From busybox
Run echo "My first command"
Run echo "My second command"
Run echo "My third command"
```

You can build a docker image with:

```
$ docker build -t abdelghany/myimage .

$ docker images
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
abdelghany/myimage            latest              159379ab5770        5 minutes ago       1.106 MB
busybox                       latest              c75bebcdd211        3 weeks ago         1.106 MB
```

Here is `docker history` of this locally built image:

```
$ docker history abdelghany/myimage
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
7a352943082a        8 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c echo "My third command"              0 B                 
6e59deae3839        8 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c echo "My second command"             0 B                 
24df2c17994f        9 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c echo "My first command"              0 B                 
c75bebcdd211        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["sh"]                   0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5dde1d6e0f6362350d   1.106 MB
```

Now, push image to a registry, delete it locally, then pull it again.

```
$ docker push abdelghany/myimage
$ docker rmi abdelghany/myimage
$ docker pull abdelghany/myimage
```

Here is the `docker history` of the pulled image:

```
$ docker history abdelghany/myimage

IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
159379ab5770        3 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c echo "My third command"              0 B                 
<missing>           3 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c echo "My second command"             0 B                 
<missing>           3 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c echo "My first command"              0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["sh"]                   0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5dde1d6e0f6362350d   1.106 MB
```

**Explanation:** docker history shows all the commands that was used to create the image layers. For locally built images, each command is associated with an intermediate image to be used in build cache (so the next time you build the image on that docker host it uses the intermediate images from cache).

When moving images around (i.e pushing and pulling), you only move the final image so when you look at the history it shows `<missing>` to indicate there is no intermediate image associated with this command, which indicates it was not built on this docker host.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if `docker history` gives you the information you are looking for.

This command gives you the commands executed by the Dockerfile, so the `MAINTAINERS` tag (or the more correct `LABEL maintainer`) may appear in the history to give you some insight into the image creator.

Comment: It's the same Dockerfile that being used in automated Docker Hub builds as well as local builds - so the `MAINTAINERS` labels are identical. I've updated the original question to provide mode context.