# How do I know that Docker is local and not push to Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, vps

Recently, I want to take over a host. It is hosted on a Linux virtual server and has a static website running on nginx inside Docker.

I am very new to docker and I read [this article](https://medium.com/@tony.aloysius.77/deploying-your-static-website-with-ease-using-nginx-35cca659079f), which explains the steps to build a static website in Docker, and at one stage it is said that the images should be pushed to Docker Hub. I requested the person who delivers the host to give me the user and password of Docker Hub and he claimed that the host site do not have Docker Hub.

How can I find out that all docker images are local and not pushed to docker hub?
I am afraid that after the delivery of the host, they will change the password of Docker Hub and the site will not be up anymore.

​
I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44464426), However, I can't understand it.
It's the command for docker history:

```
 docker image history username/oursite-website:1
```

And it's the result:

```
43106039d4xx   3 months ago   CMD ["npm" "run" "start"]                       0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   EXPOSE map[3000/tcp:{}]                         0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   COPY /app/package.json ./ # buildkit            1.01kB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   COPY /app/public ./public # buildkit            2.45MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   COPY /app/next.config.js ./ # buildkit          148B      buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   COPY /app/.next ./.next # buildkit              332MB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   COPY /app/node_modules ./node_modules # buil…   470MB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   WORKDIR /app/                                   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   ENV NODE_ENV=production                         0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1                   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["node"]                 0B
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…   0B
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:4d192567220e13…     388B
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --virtual .bui…   7.77MB
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV YARN_VERSION=1.22.19     0B
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c addgroup -g 1000 node     && addu…   162MB
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NODE_VERSION=18.18.0     0B
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
<missing>      5 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:32ff5e7a78b0996…     7.34MB
```

And it's my images:

```
[root@ourwebsite ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                          TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
portal                              1               f83a7da54axx   2 days ago     194MB
entrance                            1               a9f7590e22xx   2 days ago     889MB
certbot/certbot                     <none>          2fe8e0aa5fxx   5 weeks ago    114MB
username/ourwebsite-website         1               43106039d4xx   3 months ago   981MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          61719d3399xx   3 months ago   981MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          47f292d6a9xx   3 months ago   959MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          5198c9fc75xx   3 months ago   959MB
username/ourwebsite-api             1               d3340707ecxx   4 months ago   318MB
username/ourwebsite-website         2               efedf06ddaxx   4 months ago   937MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          18ef9ec65axx   4 months ago   44.5MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          dbf80ff520xx   4 months ago   44.5MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          1f1b094c55xx   4 months ago   44.5MB
username/ourwebsite-api             <none>          1d4311fcddxx   4 months ago   318MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          3be1c6481dxx   4 months ago   44.5MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          3362f5d021xx   4 months ago   44.4MB
username/ourwebsite-website         <none>          fcc710ce9axx   4 months ago   44.4MB
username/ourwebsite-api             <none>          c637b62983xx   4 months ago   318MB
<none>                              <none>          9fb390790bxx   4 months ago   875MB
<none>                              <none>          09704e9bd4xx   5 months ago   174MB
nginx                               stable-alpine   6dae3976eexx   5 months ago   41.1MB
certbot/certbot                     latest          2924483b97xx   8 months ago   96.6MB
nginx                               <none>          0cd1271146xx   9 months ago   41.1MB
postgres                            15.2-alpine     ddc12ac7faxx   9 months ago   243MB
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but images that run on a host are always taken from the local repository. If you want to run a Docker Hub image, then the image is first pulled (copied) to the local repository and then run from there. After the image is pulled, you can always run the image, even if Docker Hub is unavailable.